# Multiple language form validation using jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form on a site that is in English and French, is there a way to display the correct language error messages based on the language using jquery validation plug in?

I tried a url based approach which works but only displays the ONE "required" message and I need to have all the custom messages displayed for each form item that will be validated.

jQuery:

```
 var url = location.pathname;

   if (url.indexOf("representative-fr.html") > -1)  {
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            required: "Ce champ est obligatoire."
        });
    } else {
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
           required: "This field is mandatory."
        });
    }
```

What I am trying to do:

```
  if (url.indexOf("representative-fr.html") > -1) {
    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
      howToContact: "Please select a contact option", (this will be in french)
      firstName: "Please enter your first name",      (this will be in french)
      lastName: "Please enter your last name",        (this will be in french)
    });
  } else {
    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
      howToContact: "Please select a contact option",
      firstName: "Please enter your first name",
      lastName: "Please enter your last name",
    });
  }
```

Comment: That looks like it should work.  So  what happened when you tried it?  The plugin also has  localization options.  Perhaps instead  just load the proper localization file based on page?

Comment: I thought it would work like that too, but when I run it it only shows the "required" message and not the custom ones I set per the input "name" such as howToContact

Comment: That's because "howToContact" is set by your custom method... presumably, since you control the page, you already control the message.  In other words, when you load the French page, load the version of your custom method with the French message inside.